# Validating a TextBox if a Checkbox is checked (inside GridView)

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have the following markup in an ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataSourceID="ods" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
    <columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbx" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I validate the `TextBox` only if the `CheckBox` is checked?

I searched for similar situations, but couldn't find anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

U can use RowCommand under which u can get the control status using int index = AuthorsGridView.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = AuthorsGridView.Rows[index];  and then validate the text box

refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx